Empty Metadata table in Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin of QGIS
I am working on Landsat 8 images using QGIS 3.36.2
When I want to convert clipped images to reflectance in Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin, nothing is displayed under the metadata table even though I have selected the correct directory containing band and the correct metadata file.
How can I resolve this issue?
I am attaching the image for reference.


Maybe this? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/481396/2856

@user2856 Thanks a lot. It helped.

Posting about how my issue got resolved in case someone needs it.
As per @user2856's comment, I checked out this answer:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/481396/243746
But adding _MTL.txt file to the directory did not work for me. So I added _MTL.xml file instead. That worked!
